# How to use bundling and minification for scripts embedded in an assembly?

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I am using an [obout HtmlEditor](http://www.obout.com/editor_new/sample_full.aspx) in my application and I would like to use bundling and minification support for all the script that are embedded in the dll.
For example in my case I am using an obout editor and the following js are embedded in the obouteditor.dll:

```
Obout.Ajax.UI.Common.Common.js
Obout.Ajax.UI.Common.Library.js
Obout.Ajax.UI.HTMLEditor.Front.Toolbar.js
```

How can I combine all this scripts into a single bundle and minify?
Note: I don't want to use AjaxControlToolscriptManager and want to use asp.net 4.5 bundling and minification or any other alternative.